# Proof of weak convergence of empirical measure

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, weak-convergence

Let's say that we have a complete and separable metric space in other words a Polish space $(S, d)$.

If we say that we have $n$ I.I.D random elements $(Y_0, Y_1 ...)$ in our space $S$ with a common distribution that we'll denote $P$. If we define an empirical measure $P_{n,w}$ using observations $(Y_1(w), ..., Y_n(w))$.

$$P_{n,w} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\delta_{X_i}(w)$$

Where the $\delta_x$ is a measure that places a unit mass on $x$. How do we show that given that S is seperable and complete, then $P_{n,w} \rightarrow P$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$ The convergence is weak.

Could we use the equivalences from Portmanteau theorem's to prove this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For each continuous bounded function $g: S\to\mathbb{R}$, we have
$$\lim_n\int g~\mathrm dP_{n,w}=\int g~\mathrm dP$$ for $P$-almost all $w$ by the strong law of large numbers. This is not enough because there is a continuum of such functions and the union of all the relevant null sets may have positive measure. But there exist countably many bounded continuous functions such that convergence of their integrals implies already convergence for all bounded continuous functions. This is basically equivalent to the separability of the topology of weak convergence of probability measures, which you can find in many places. If you want the original source, it is:

> Varadarajan, V. S. "On the convergence of sample probability
>   distributions." Sankhyā: The Indian Journal of Statistics (1933-1960)
>   19.1/2 (1958): 23-26.

To make the connection with separability more explicit: The weak topology is generated by functions of the form $\mu\mapsto\int g~\mathrm d\mu.$ Therefore, every open set in the weak topology is the union of finite intersections of preimages of open sets of reals under such functions. Now in a metrizable space, being separable is equivalent to having a countable basis. So let $D$ be a countable dense set of probability measures and $\mathcal{B}$ a countable basis of the weak topology. There are countably many pairs $(\mu,O)$ with $\mu\in D$, $O\in\mathcal{B}$, and $\mu\in O$. For each such pair, there is a finite set of $G_{\mu,O}$ of bounded continuous functions of $S$ such that for some family $\{V_g\mid g\in G_{\mu,O}\}$ of open sets of reals, we have
$$\mu\in\bigcap_{g\in G_{\mu,O}}g^{-1}(V_g)\subseteq O.$$
It follows that sets of the form $$\bigcap_{g\in G_{\mu,O}}g^{-1}(V_g)$$ form themselves a countable basis of the weak topology. Now each such set requires only finitely many bounded continuous functions of $S$ and the countable union of finite sets is countable again, so we can do with countably many such functions. Specifically, the sequence of probability measures $\langle \mu_n\rangle$ converges to $\mu$ if and only if $$\lim_n\int g~\mathrm d\mu_n=\int g~\mathrm d\mu$$ for each $g\in\bigcup_{(\mu,O)} G_{\mu,O}$.

Conversely, if we have such a countable family of functions, there is a countable basis consisting of finite intersections of preimages of intervals with rational endpoints under the induced functions of probability measures.

Comment: Could you expand more on how we can use the fact that S is separable in order to prove this? I'm having trouble seeing the connection.

Comment: @FrancoisWassert I've added the details.

Comment: "union of all the relevant null sets may have positive measure", don't null sets have zero measure by construction?

Comment: @FrancoisWassert Yes, but the union of null sets need not be a null set. Each singleton has Lebesgue measure zero, but $[0,1]=\bigcup_{x\in[0,1]}\{x\}$ does not.

Comment: Could you please explain why? 
https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Null_Sets_Closed_under_Countable_Union
This seems to show the opposite.

Comment: @FrancoisWassert Your link only considers countable union, so the only way it could fail is with an uncountable union, like Michael Greinecker's counterexample.

Comment: Hello, I might be a bit late, but can I aska question @michael greneker? In order to show that e sequence of measures converges weakly isn't it enough to show it for all bounded continuous function, i. e. why isn't your first line enough?

Comment: @asdf It only shows that for all such functions $g$ there exists a set of measure $1$ such that the $g$-integrals converge to the appropriate limit. But we need to reverse quantifiers and show that there exists a set of measure $1$ such that for all $g$  the $g$-integrals converge to the appropriate limit.

Comment: But isn't the weak topology induced by convergence against continuous bounded functions? Hence, in order to show that weak convergence holds for a sequence of measures holds  it should suffice to look at the continuous and bounded functions only? Either that, or I have to go back to the definitions :)

Comment: @asdf You want to have almost sure convergence in the weak topology, both notions of convergence have to be combined here. The sequence of sample distributions is random.

Comment: But doesn't he want to have just weak convergence? For which I assume convergence against continuous bounded functions is enough?

Comment: @asdf Every sample realization gives a different sequence of probability measures? Which one of these sequences should converge? Almost all do, but not all.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Ah, I see, I didn't realise that the measures are random and you need a.s. convergence in order to take into account the dependence on the $\omega$'s - sorry it took me so long. Thanks a lot!