# Convergence of kernel density estimator

Tags: measure-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, weak-convergence

**Does the smoothed empirical measure of a sample from probability distribution $P$ converge to $P$?**

More precisely, let $P$ be a measure on the real line, absolutely continuous wrt the Lebesgue measure, with probability density function $f$. Let $x_i, i=1...n$ be an iid sample from $P$ and $P^n$ be the empirical measure $\frac{1}{n}\sum \delta_{x_i}$. Let $P^n \ast \phi$ be a smoothed empirical measure with gaussian mollifier $\phi = N(0,\varepsilon)$ for some $\varepsilon$. Explicitly, the pdf of the smoothed empirical measure is
$$(P^n \ast \phi)(x) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \phi(x-x_i) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (2\pi \varepsilon)^{-1/2} \exp\left(\frac{-(x-x_i)^2}{2\varepsilon}\right).$$
**My questions are**:

1. Does $P^n \ast \phi$ converge to $P$ in L2 or L1? In the sense that for $p=1,2$,
   $$\int_\mathbb{R} \left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_i \phi(x-x_i) - f\right|^p dx \to 0.$$
2. Does $P^n \ast \phi$ converge to $P$ weakly almost surely? In the sense that with probability 1, for any bounded continuous function $g$,
   $$\int_\mathbb{R} \frac{1}{n}\sum_i \phi(x-x_i)g(x)dx \to \int_\mathbb{R} f(x)g(x)dx.$$
3. Does $P^n \ast \phi$ converge to $P$ in distribution almost surely? In the sense that with probability 1, for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$,
   $$ \frac{1}{n}\sum_i \phi(x-x_i) \to f(x).$$
4. Does 1, 2 or 3 become true if $\varepsilon = o(1/n)$ instead of being fixed?

I am almost certain that question 1 is false. If epsilon is allowed to decay to 0 with $n\to\infty$, I think question 2 should be a positive because $\phi_{x_i} \ast \delta_{x_i} \to \delta_{x_i}$ weakly as variance shrinks to 0.

Perhaps it would be helpful to note that the empirical measure $P^n$ does converge to $P$ weakly almost surely, which is a consequence of the strong law of large numbers. Proof of this is the first answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2602960/proof-of-weak-convergence-of-empirical-measure)

Comment: This is also known as [Gaussian kernel density estimator](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) and there is a lot of research on it. Look it up.

Comment: @Snoop this is very useful! Do you have a good reference on KDEs? Wikipedia doesn't seem to have that much.

Comment: Unfortunately not that I can recall now, but you may ask a question for specific references (which level you may need of sophistication on these estimators) either here or on CrossValidated since this would be on topic on both.